# What happens to old publisher name on google play after name change

Tags: android, google-play, publisher

I recently registered a company name and would like to change my Google Play publisher name.

The problem is that i don't know what happens to the old publisher name. 
I have a lot of links to my apps on websites and even within the apps.
Example Link:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=old_publisher_name

I don't want the old store-link to be broken.

Has anybody successfully changed the publisher name and can me tell his experience?
Is the old name still reserved and referencing to the new name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is not preserved and does become broken. I have changed developer names 3 times and this is one of the biggest pains to deal with.